# How do I join these two objects without causing non-manifold edges?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I am trying to design an arch shaped fan guard.

I created a long "cube" and then used the simple deform>bend to turn it into an arch shape.

Then I created a plane, removed the centre, extruded upwards and use an array to make the grid.

Then I used boolean transformations to remove the bits of grid that I don't need and joined the two objects using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> .

However now I am trying to fix any non-manifold edges etc. so that it is 3D printable please can you advise how I fix these?

[image]

Or if there is a much easier way of producing this object that would also help.

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: In Edit mode use the Select menu -> Select All by Trait -> Non-Manifold. Then manually fix the issue.

Comment: I don't really know how to fix the issue. There is one edge, but I don't know what is actually wrong with it.

Comment: I think the issue seems to be that it has not gotten rid of the faces where the grid meets the arch. Selecting internal faces doesn't seem to select them

Comment: can you post the .blend and we can have a look https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have added it to the edit, This is a few saves back, before the objects are joined.

Comment: Neither of the two objects in that file have any non-manifold edges. If I use the Boolean modifier to Union them, the default options creates a lot of non-manifold edges. But, if I use the Boolean modifier with Union and set the Solver to Carve the result is manifold. Let me know if that worked for you and I will put it in an answer for others to find.

Comment: @rob thank you, that seems to work much better. No manifold edges, but I did still have a few intersecting faces and zero edges. Do they not matter as much?

Comment: I think that depends on your slicer/3D printer.